# How to apply styles in Amchart-Stockchart

Tags: javascript, css, amcharts

I am trying to apply various Styles in my own Amchart-Stockchart, one such can be viewed in https://codepen.io/Volabos/pen/xywPdb

However I failed to apply below 2 stylings :

1. I want to `fill the area under line` till the x-axis with light `Alpha` value. I found one option with `fillAlpha`, however I couldnt not be able to apply this option.
2. In the `Zoom` option, I want to apply different styles e.g. different background color for different zoom options, Fonts etc. I was wondering if I could warp them within various `Divs` and place them in other suitable spaces in the Webpage.

Is it possible to achieve them? Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is called [fillAlpha**s**](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#fillAlphas) - you're missing the `s` at the end:

```
stockGraphs: [{
  // ...
  fillAlphas: .5
},
// ...
]
```

This is also the case setting the fill color - the property is `fillColors` with an `s`. You'll need to set [`useDataSetColors`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#useDataSetColors) to false if you want to use a different color than the one specified in the dataSet.

You can't wrap the `periodSelector` zoom options in a div and move them around like you can with legends. You can style the the `periodSelector` components by setting [`addClassNames`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#addClassNames) to true and apply the desired CSS to the elements associated with the period selector using the classes listed [here](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/css-class-names/). Note that you can position the `periodSelector` by setting its `position` property to `"top"`, `"left"`, `"right"` or `"bottom"`.

Here's a [demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/aa9067c5f4ea8b267745fb879a335854/?editors=0110) illustrating `fillAlphas` and `addClassNames`.

Comment: Thanks for this Demo. While now I am able to style many parameters but still few failed. E.g. how can I control Border and Border radius for .amcharts-period-input, .amcharts-period-input-selected, .amcharts-start-date-input, .amcharts-end-date-input? When I put 0 weight for border and border radius nothing change (refer to the pen) - Do I need to look for some other class?

Comment: Some styles are set inline by the chart itself so you need to use `!important` to override this. Note that I did this with the background color for the selected button.